# Getting the java.lang.reflect.Method from a ProceedingJoinPoint?

Tags: spring, jakarta-ee, aop, aspectj, spring-aop

The question is short and simple: Is there a way to get the Method object from an apsectj  ProceedingJoinPoint?

Currently I am doing

```
Class[] parameterTypes = new Class[joinPoint.getArgs().length];
Object[] args = joinPoint.getArgs();
for(int i=0; i<args.length; i++) {
    if(args[i] != null) {
        parameterTypes[i] = args[i].getClass();
    }
    else {
        parameterTypes[i] = null;
    }
}

String methodName = joinPoint.getSignature().getName();
Method method = joinPoint.getSignature()
    .getDeclaringType().getMethod(methodName, parameterTypes);
```

but I don't think this is the way to go ...

Answer (score 104, accepted):

Your method is not wrong, but there's a better one. You have to cast to [`MethodSignature`](http://www.eclipse.org/aspectj/doc/released/runtime-api/org/aspectj/lang/reflect/MethodSignature.html)

```
MethodSignature signature = (MethodSignature) joinPoint.getSignature();
Method method = signature.getMethod();
```

Comment: When used in spring boot application the above cast fails. The signature is  then is of type MethodSignatureImpl which is a private inner class of springs MethodInvocationProceedingJoinPoint.

Comment: Update to above comment (which is wrong): In my test I imported the wrong MethodSignature class which led to a ClassCastException. The correct class is org.aspectj.lang.reflect.MethodSignature.

Comment: How could I do this, but instead of get the method, get the class where the method is placed? Would `MethodSignature#getDeclaringType()` do it?

Comment: But developer should be sure, joinpoint is method not constructor right? Otherwise ClassCastException. Please correct me if I am wrong.

Answer (score 48):

You should be careful because `Method method = signature.getMethod()` will return the method of the interface, you should add this to be sure to get the method of the implementation class:

```
    if (method.getDeclaringClass().isInterface()) {
        try {
            method= jointPoint.getTarget().getClass().getDeclaredMethod(jointPoint.getSignature().getName(),
                    method.getParameterTypes());
        } catch (final SecurityException exception) {
            //...
        } catch (final NoSuchMethodException exception) {
            //...                
        }
    }
```

(The code in catch is voluntary empty, you better add code to manage the exception)

With this you'll have the implementation if you want to access method or parameter annotations if this one are not in the interface

Comment: I'd upvote you twice if I could, once for the great answer, and once for `jointpoint`